# first attempt at learning oracle triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am just starting to learn triggers so please bear with me.  If the row being inserted has a gift that is the same as any gift already in the table, print a message saying that the gift was already given to receiver from donor.

```
create or replace TRIGGER Same_Gift_Given
  BEFORE INSERT ON GIVING
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  giftgiven varchar(255);
BEGIN
  SELECT giftname INTO giftgiven from GIVING;
  IF :new.giftname = giftgiven then
    dbms_output.put_line(giftgiven || ' has already been gifted to ' || giving.receiver || ' by ' || giving.donor);
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  In reality, it makes no sense to use a trigger to enforce this sort of requirement-- you would use a unique constraint.

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is hw.

Comment: OK, and you are certain that the professor requires you to use a trigger?  I'm guessing that the professor hasn't talked about mutating trigger exceptions.  Is it safe to assume that you only need to support statements of the form `INSERT INTO giving VALUES( ...` and that your trigger is allowed to throw errors when people use the more general `INSERT INTO giving SELECT` syntax?  Is it safe to assume that the trigger only needs to work for single-user systems and is allowed to fail for multi-user systems?

Comment: Yes these are all safe assumptions.  As I already said, I'm just learning and this is my first introduction to triggers.

Answer (score 4):

This is a really awful homework problem.  You would never, ever, ever us a trigger to do anything like this in a real system.  It will break most `INSERT` operations and it will fail if there are ever multiple users.  In reality, you would use a constraint.  In reality, if for some reason you were forced at gunpoint to use a trigger, you would need a series of three triggers, a package, and a collection to do it properly.

**What the professor is probably looking for**

Just to emphasize, though, you would never, ever consider doing this in a real system

```
create or replace trigger same_gift_given
  before insert on giving
  for each row
declare
  l_existing_row giving%rowtype;
begin
  select *
    into l_existing_row
    from giving
   where giftname = :new.giftname
     and rownum = 1;

  dbms_output.put_line( :new.giftname || 
                           ' has already been gifted to ' ||
                           l_existing_row.receiver ||
                           ' from ' ||
                           l_existing_row.donor );
exception
  when no_data_found
  then
    null;
end;
```

This does not prevent you from inserting duplicate rows.  It will throw a mutating trigger error if you try to do anything other than an `INSERT ... VALUES` on the `giving` table.  It is inefficient.  It does not handle multiple sessions.  In short, it is absolutely atrocious code that should never be used in any real system.

**What you would do in reality**

In reality, you would create a constraint

```
ALTER TABLE giving
  ADD CONSTRAINT unique_gift UNIQUE( giftname );
```

That will work in a multi-user environment.  It will not throw a mutating trigger exception.  It is much more efficient.  It is much less code.  It actually prevents duplicate rows from being inserted.

Comment: Thank you.  For my sake, could you clarify what is going on?  What is giving%rowtype and why are you assigning rownum = 1?

Comment: @user1657563 - `giving%rowtype` is a record that is based on a single row of the `giving` table.  You could create two separate local variables, `l_receiver` and `l_donor` and select both the `receiver` and the `donor` in the `SELECT` statement as well.  Since the trigger does not actually prevent you from inserting multiple rows with the same `giftname`, the `rownum = 1` predicate arbitrarily picks one of the duplicate gifts in order to prevent the query from throwing a `too_many_rows` exception when there are multiple duplicate gifts.

Comment: Trigger is invalid and failed re-validation.  Cause: A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization failed for the trigger.

Comment: @user1657563 - When you create the trigger, assuming you are using SQL*Plus, type "show errors" to show the errors.  I had a stray semicolon inadvertently, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something a bit different:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GIVING_COMPOUND_INSERT
  FOR INSERT ON GIVING
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  TYPE STRING_COL IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(255);

  colGiftnames   STRING_COL;
  aGiftname      VARCHAR2(255);
  nCount         NUMBER;

  -- Note that the way the associative array is used here is a bit of a cheat.
  -- In the BEFORE EACH ROW block I'm putting the string of interest into the
  -- collection as both the value *and* the index.  Then, when iterating the
  -- collection only the index is used - the value is never retrieved (but
  -- since it's the same as the index, who cares?).  I do this because I'd
  -- rather not write code to call a constructor and maintain the collections
  -- size - so I just use an associative array and let Oracle do the work for
  -- me.

  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    colGiftnames(:NEW.GIFTNAME) := :NEW.GIFTNAME;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    aGiftname := colGiftnames.FIRST;
    WHILE aGiftname IS NOT NULL LOOP
      SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO nCount
        FROM GIVING
        WHERE GIFTNAME = aGiftname;

      IF nCount > 1 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found ' || nCount || ' instances of gift ''' ||
                             aGiftname || '''');
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Found ' || nCount ||
                                        ' instances of gift ''' ||
                                        aGiftname || '''');
      END IF;

      aGiftname := colGiftnames.NEXT(aGiftname);
    END LOOP;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END GIVING_COMPOUND_INSERT;
```

Again, this is a LOUSY way to try to guarantee uniqueness.  In practice the "right way" to do this is with a constraint (either UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY).  Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.

Share and enjoy.